# ERROR: connection for foreign table "test_enames" cannot be established

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, oracle-fdw

I am getting below error while selecting the foreign table from Postgres & please help me on fixing the issue.

> **ERROR**: connection for foreign table "test_enames" cannot be established
>
> DETAIL: **ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
> specified**
>
> SQL state: **HV00N**

**Details**

1.I am using Postgres 13 version on Windows 10 64 Bit machine.

2.I installed **oracle_fdw-2.3.0-pg13-win64** successfully in my Windows 10 6bit machine.

3.Created system variable for **TNS_ADMIN**=C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0x64\client_1\network\admin

4.Created below steps successfully.

```
CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw

CREATE SERVER foreign_oracle
TYPE 'Oracle12'
VERSION '12'
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw
OPTIONS (dbserver '//vms1.abc.com:1524/ABC00D70');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER foreign_oracle
OPTIONS ("user" 'Test', password 'Test1');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE test_enames(
eno numeric NULL,
ename character varying(100),
eloc character varying(100)
) SERVER foreign_oracle
OPTIONS (table 'TEST_ENAMES');
```

But still getting error while selecting table , let me know incase if i missed any steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That seems like an Oracle configuration problem.
To debug this, try running the following as the operating system user that runs the PostgreSQL service:

```sh
sqlplus Test/Test1@//vms150.abc.com:1524/ABC00D70
```

If that doesn't work, start debugging that. That should be easier, since oracle_fdw is not part of the equation then.

If the sqlplus call above works as you intend it to, make sure that the PostgreSQL service has the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable set (did you restart the service after setting it?). I am not sure how to check the environment for a running process on Windows, but "Process Explorer" might do the trick.

Besides, you shouldn't use `CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` to create the FDW, but create the extension as specified in the documentation:

```
CREATE EXTENSION oracle_fdw;
```

That will create the foreign data wrapper for you.

Comment: Issue has been fixed with below correction.

Comment: CREATE SERVER foreign_oracle
TYPE 'Oracle12'
VERSION '12'
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw
OPTIONS (dbserver 'ABC00D70');

Comment: Yes, an Oracle configuration problem.